# Getting "Invalid json" error when creating iam-role using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, assume-role

I'm getting an error when trying to create a new role using aws cli.

Here is the error message.

```
An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the CreateRole operation: This policy contains invalid Json
```

In other to crate a role, I run following command.

```
aws iam create-role --path /role-service/ --role-name Test-Role --assume-role-policy-document policy.json
```

and the policy.json is

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "sts:ExternalId": "d611c8fd-0fd1-469a-a5ea-b02186042023"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How did it go? The issue still persist?

Answer (score 4):

You should be using `file://` as explained in:

- [Loading AWS CLI parameters from a file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-file.html)

Therefore, you can try the following if `policy.json` in your current working directory:

```
aws iam create-role --path /role-service/ --role-name Test-Role --assume-role-policy-document file://policy.json
```

Comment: But, if the policy.json file is in specific directory in current directory, how to point the path?

Comment: @Venus713 You can provide full path to it. For example if its in `/tmp/` you can `file:///tmp/policy.json`. The link in the answer has more examples.

Comment: ```aws iam create-role --path /service-role/ --role-name test-role --assume-role-policy-document file:///src/actions/export/server/role-trust-policy.json```
I run the command above and got following error.
```Error parsing parameter '--assume-role-policy-document': Unable to load paramfile file:///src/actions/export/server/role-trust-policy.json: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/src/actions/export/server/role-trust-policy.json'```

Comment: @Venus713 probably you have wrong path. If `/src/actions/export/server/role-trust-policy.json` actually exists, the command is correct.